# Are Python function parameters enclosed in tuples or just conventional parentheses?

Tags: python

Are functions passed parameters enclosed in parentheses because they are handled as tuples, or just a result of f(x) convention?

i.e. is (b, a, r) a tuple here:

```
def foo(b, a, r):
    pass
```

Or, is it something more like the way parentheses are used in math equations, e.g.

```
>>> 3 * 2 + 1
7
>>> 3 * (2 + 1)
9
```

Comment: Those parenthesis are part of a specific syntax for function definitions and function calls. They are not tuples, nor normal parenthesis.

Comment: How is this unclear question? Good explanation with examples, no need to downvote him.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: this is easily researched however. I don't see any research references; the [Python reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference) is very well written, and the answer lies within that documentation. There's the [call expression section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls), or the [parenthesized forms](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms) or [expression list](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists) sections. Or read up about tuples on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good point, that is true and justifies the downvotes. Still, an instant -3 score with no explanation (until yours now) isn't really helping anyone. Someone also voted to close as "unclear what you're asking", so I thought the downvote(s) were for that too.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: I can't speak for anyone who voted to close, nor why anyone might have voted; it was mere speculation on my part as to what the question is lacking in my eyes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes of course, I was just mentioning generally, in case some of the downvoters who didn't care to explain their vote happen to read it  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can answer this by looking at the [Python Grammar.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html)

The relevant lines are:

```
funcdef: 'def' NAME parameters ['->' test] ':' suite
parameters: '(' [typedargslist] ')'
```

So in your example, the grammar would say that `(b, a, r)` is a `typedargslist` surrounded by brackets.

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't see those as tuples. Tuples don't take `keyword=value` arguments, for example, but the call syntax *does*.

Tuples are not formed by parentheses *anyway*, they are formed by **commas**, and you only have to use parentheses around a tuple when disambiguating a tuple from other uses of commas in Python. Like in a function call, where commas separate positional arguments.

The Python grammar defines both the parentheses and commas in a call as [part of the call expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations):

> ```
> call                 ::=  primary "(" [argument_list [","]
>                           | expression genexpr_for] ")"
> ```

while elsewhere tuples are defined as being formed by commas. See [*expression lists*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists):

> ```
> expression_list ::=  expression ( "," expression )* [","]
> ```
>
> An expression list containing at least one comma yields a tuple. The length of the tuple is the number of expressions in the list.

Note that only the `","` commas are part of the literal syntax, the `(...)` parentheses here are part of the syntax defining the grammar.

The other use of parentheses (grouping expressions) is defined in [*parethezised forms*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms):

> A parenthesized form is an optional expression list enclosed in parentheses, note again the literal `"("` and `")"` characters:
>
> ```
> parenth_form ::=  "(" [expression_list] ")"
> ```
>
> A parenthesized expression list yields whatever that expression list yields: if the list contains at least one comma, it yields a tuple; otherwise, it yields the single expression that makes up the expression list.

There are a few more places in the Python grammar where parentheses are used, see the [full grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html); these usually echo either the call syntax (e.g. [function](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) and [class](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) definitions, decorators) or the parenthesised form (grouping imported names, for example), plus [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).